# (Spring Boot, Maven) Why do I get 404 error when I submit the form?

Tags: html, forms, maven, spring-boot, freemarker

Using Spring Boot, when I submit a form, it returns 404 error. And it doesn't give me any hint what is missing. Could you tell me what's wrong?

This is the HTML code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <#include "fragment/head.ftl">
</head>
<body class="body-home mdl-layout mdl-js-layout">
    <header class="form">
        <h1>${viewmsg}</h1>
    </header>
    <main class="mdl-layout__content">

        <div class="mdl-grid">
            <form class="mdl-card mdl-shadow-2dp mdl-cell--12-col" method="POST"
                  action="${action}" role="form">
                <#include "content/form/${view}.ftl">
                <div class="mdl-cell--12-col mdl-grid btn-wrapper">
                    <button class="mdl-button mdl-js-button mdl-button--raised mdl-button--colored mdl-cell--12-col" type="submit">
                        Submit
                    </button>
                </div>
            </form>

        </div>

    </main>

</body>
</html>
```

This is a part of the Controller code:

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/join", method = RequestMethod.GET)
public ModelAndView join() {
        ModelAndView mv = new ModelAndView("form");
        mv.addObject("layout", "form");
        mv.addObject("view", "createMember");
        mv.addObject("viewmsg", "Sign In");
        mv.addObject("action", "/member/join");
        mv.addObject("modelName", "member");
        Member member = new Member();
        mv.addObject("member", member);
        return mv;
}

@RequestMapping(value = "/join", method = RequestMethod.POST)
public ModelAndView create(@RequestParam("name") String name, @RequestParam("id") String id, @RequestParam("password") String password) {
        logger.debug("aaaa");
        Member member = new Member();
        member.setId(id);
        member.setName(name);
        member.setPassword(password);
        ModelAndView mv = new ModelAndView();

        try {
            memberService.create(member);
        }
        catch (Exception e) {
            mv.addObject("layout", "form");
            mv.addObject("view", "createMember");
            mv.addObject("viewmsg", "Sign In");
            mv.addObject("action", "/member/join");
            mv.addObject("member", member);
            mv.addObject("modelName", "member");
            mv.addObject("error", e.getMessage());

            return mv;
        }

        mv.setViewName("redirect:/");
        mv.addObject("view", "home");
        mv.addObject("member", member);
        return mv;
}
```

At the beginnig of the function *create*, I let it print "aaaa", but it doesn't. So I think the error is caused before *create*.

Comment: Your submit button flow is missing. It's been long I worked with JSPs but Submit button needs to know your controller URL and also your model name is missing in <form> tag.

Comment: Doesn't the 'action' property give the controller URL?

Comment: Correct!!! My bad. Can you share your exception? If I cant dry run I would quickly set up to give you a solution.

Comment: Yes, you can. What should I do?